# Javascript: How to Stop Word Loop

Tags: javascript

I have a JS loop on my homepage.
but I'm not sure how I can stop on the word 'come simple'

```
<h2 class = 'open'> Life Can Be <span class = 'changeable'><b>Radical</b></span></h2>

        <script>
            var c=0, words=['Interesting','Fun','Exciting','Crazy', 'Simple'];
          function loop(){
            $('h2 span').delay(1000).fadeTo(300,0,function(){
               $(this).text( words[++c%words.length] ).fadeTo(300,1,loop);
            });
          }    
          loop(); // start it!
        </script>
```

If you need more information,please let me know instead of down voting. I'm new to Javascript, and can't seem to find the solution, I may be overlooking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.fadeTo()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) takes 3rd optional argument `complete` as a function to call once the animation is complete, and this is where recursion happens.

we wanted to stop the recursion when counter is just before the last element of the array

i.e. `c < words.length - 1`

```js
var c = 0,
  words = ['Interesting', 'Fun', 'Exciting', 'Crazy', 'Simple'];

function loop() {
  $('h2 span').delay(1000).fadeTo(300, 0, function() {

    $(this).text(words[++c]).fadeTo(300, 1, c < words.length - 1 ? loop : null);
  });
}
loop(); // start it!
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class='open'> Life Can Be <span class = 'changeable'><b>Radical</b></span></h2>
```

Comment: Care to explain your solution?